# How to interpret the bandwidth value in a kernel density estimation?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I'm not sure how to interpret the value of the bandwidth parameter in kernel density estimations. Let's say I if the values range from 1 to 20. How would I need to set the bandwidth, so that each kernel ranges over two. For example, if I want to set the kernel above the point 10, then the kernel should range from [9,11], if above 15 then [14,16]. Would that simply be the bandwidth of 2?
The goal is to attach some meaning to the bandwidth.

Comment: You interpret it more or less correctly with that nuance that the correct interpretation depends on the kernel that you choose

Comment: think of the KDE as a smoothed version of the histogram

Comment: So, the bandwidth value specifies the "range of points" covered on the x axis and the type of kernel specifies its height and shapre. Is that correct?

Comment: Which bandwidth to choose is also somewhat dependent on the kernel you are using, e.g. for a uniform kernel
$$K(x)\propto \mathbf{1}_{[|x|\leq1]}$$ 
a bandwidth $h=2$ would mean that $K( (x-x_i)\cdot h^{-1})$ would be nonzero around $[x_i-2, x_i+2]$.

Answer (score 8):

For simplicity, let's assume that we are talking about some really simple kernel, say triangular kernel:

$$ K(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 - |x| & \text{if } x \in [-1, 1] \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Recall that in [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) for estimating density $\hat f_h$ we combine $n$ kernels parametrized by $h$ centered at points $x_i$:

$$
\hat{f}_h(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_h (x - x_i) = \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n K\Big(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\Big)
$$

Notice that by $\frac{x-x_i}{h}$ we mean that we want to re-scale the difference of some $x$ with point $x_i$ by factor $h$. Most of the [kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use) (excluding Gaussian) are limited to the $(-1, 1)$ range, so this means that they will return densities equal to zero for points out of $(x_i-h, x_i+h)$ range. Saying it differently, $h$ is [scale parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-scale_family) for kernel, that changes it's range from $(-1, 1)$ to $(-h, h)$.

This is illustrated on the plot below, where $n=7$ points are used for estimating kernel densities with different bandwidthes $h$ (colored points on top mark the individual values, colored lines are the kernels, gray line is overall kernel estimate). As you can see, $h < 1$ makes the kernels narrower, while $h > 1$ makes them wider. Changing $h$ influences both the individual kernels and the final kernel density estimate, since it's a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of individual kernels. Higher $h$ makes the kernel density estimate smoother, while as $h$ gets smaller it leads to kernels being closer to individual datapoints, and with $h \rightarrow 0$ you would end up with just a bunch of [Direc delta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) centered at $x_i$ points.

[image: Examples of KDE estimates with h=0.5, h=1, h=1.5, h=2]

And the R code that produced the plots:

```r
set.seed(123)
n <- 7
x <- rnorm(n, sd = 3)

K <- function(x) ifelse(x >= -1 & x <= 1, 1 - abs(x), 0)

kde <- function(x, data, h, K) {
  n <- length(data)
  out <- outer(x, data, function(xi,yi) K((xi-yi)/h))
  rowSums(out)/(n*h)
} 

xx = seq(-8, 8, by = 0.001)
for (h in c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2)) {
  plot(NA, xlim = c(-4, 8), ylim = c(0, 0.5), xlab = "", ylab = "",
       main = paste0("h = ", h))
  for (i in 1:n) {
    lines(xx, K((xx-x[i])/h)/(n*h), type = "l", col = rainbow(n)[i])
    rug(x[i], lwd = 2, col = rainbow(n)[i], side = 3, ticksize = 0.075)
  }
  lines(xx, kde(xx, x, h, K), col = "darkgray")
}
```

For more details you can check the great introductory books by Silverman (1986) and Wand & Jones (1995).

---

Silverman, B.W. (1986). *Density estimation for statistics and data analysis.* CRC/Chapman & Hall.

Wand, M.P and Jones, M.C. (1995). *Kernel Smoothing.* London: Chapman & Hall/CRC.

Comment: Is it correct that in the innermost loop, line "lines(xx, K((xx-x[i])/h)/n ...", there is only one h, that is, no h outside the scope of K()? Or should it all additionally be divided by h like in the RHS for $\hat{f}_h$ above?

Comment: @user7427029 I'm not sure what you mean, but $h$ is here just a regular scaling hyperparameter see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation

Comment: Within the formula for kernel density estimation $\frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i = 1}^n K(\frac{x - x_i}{h})$, the scaling hyperparameter $h$ occurs at two places: within the kernel $K()$ and as coefficient $\frac{1}{nh}$ at the outside of $K()$.

But your R source code line   lines(xx, K((xx-x[i])/h)/n, type = "l", col = rainbow(n)[i])   contains the hyperscaling parameter $h$ only once (within the kernel), despite the line seems to try to implement the kernel density estimation (which uses two occurences of $h$).

Comment: @user7427029 ah, right, this seems to be a bug. Fixed it, thanks.