# Kernel density estimation -Effect of bandwidth

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, kernel-smoothing

I am trying to learn Kernel density estimation, I need help to understand how the bandwidth $h$ affects the Kernel density estimator. Consider a Gaussian Kernel $k(x)~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x^2}$. The Kernel density estimator is given by ${\hat{f}}_h (x) ~=~ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} K_h(x-X_i)$.

Clearly, $k(x)$ is independent of $h$, where does $h$ come in?
What would be ${\hat{f}}_h (x)$? How does $h$ affect the Kernel?

Thank you!

Comment: It should be e^(-0,5x^2).

Comment: An illustrated explanation for the case of two-component $x$ is posted at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/14376/664.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is that you are using the wrong formula for the Gaussian kernel. The Gaussian kernel uses [normal probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) that has the following form

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\tfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$

where the distribution with parameters $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2 = 1$ is called standard normal distribution. The formula you quote resembles it. [Gaussian kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)) is based on normal density function centered at mean $\mu=0$ and has variance $\sigma^2 = h^2$. So $h$ is the scale parameter (standard deviation) of the kernel, so it serves similar purpose as bandwidth in other kernels, where it controls the ["width" of the kernel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226232/how-to-interpret-the-bandwidth-value-in-a-kernel-density-estimation/226239#226239).

As Dan said, kernels are often defined in terms of "standard" kernel, e.g. standard triangular kernel is $K(x) = (1 - |x|)$ and the scaled kernel $K_h(x) = K(x\,/\,h)\,/\,h$. The standard form of the Gaussian kernel, is the standard normal distribution.

See also the [Why does definition of kernel include bandwidth?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285455/why-does-definition-of-kernel-include-bandwidth/285692#285692) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first equation on the [wikipedia kde article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#Definition), (and then written explicitly in the first paragraph following it)

$$K_h(x)=\frac{K(\frac{x}{h})}{h}$$